# Desktop application needs server side debugging

Tags: c, debugging, client-server, desktop-application

I am working on client server windows desktop application. The client is in VC++ and server is written in c. When the client sends the commands to server through tcp/ip, the server does some processing and returns some string. 
I want to if there are any tools which can help me in debugging at the server side(unix platform), when I run the client on windows.
Is there a way I can use GDB debugger?
Thanks in advance.
RK

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to get ssh access to the server and attach gdb to the process. It would also help if the process was compiled with debug flags.